# How does PHPMailer use oauth?

Tags: php, email, oauth, phpmailer

When sending mail in smtp format, it is known that the header and body suitable for smtp are made and sent to the smtp server.

However, there is a source that is sent using oauth, so I checked it.

PHPmailer's gmail_xoauth.php file does that.

What is the difference between using oauth here and using general smtp?

It seems to be a different method than sending using the API provided by Gmail.

Is it possible to send mail with oauth authentication using mail, the default built-in function in php? If this is possible, I would also like to check out the sources that can be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use OAuth with SMTP via an extension to SMTP's AUTH command called XOAUTH2. A server that supports it will list it amongst its capabilities in response to an EHLO command:

```
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2
```

You can see [Google's docs on this subject](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) (it can also be used with POP3 and IMAP). Similarly for [Microsoft services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth).

Actually sending the AUTH command is very easy. There is a preset structure to the auth token:

```
base64("user=" {User} "^Aauth=Bearer " {Access Token} "^A^A")
```

that results in SMTP output like this:

```
AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1zb21ldXNlckBleGFtcGxlLmNvbQFhdXRoPUJlYXJlciB5YTI5LnZGOWRmdDRxbVRjMk52YjNSbGNrQmhkSFJoZG1semRHRXVZMjl0Q2cBAQ==
```

What's difficult about XOAUTH2 is *obtaining* that access token. To get hold of it requires that you run an HTTP service (on top of whatever other services you are running) and provide it with the correct ID and secret, which you submit and receive an access token in response, which you then use in your XOAUTH2 request. PHPMailer provides a script that helps you to do this for Google, Microsoft and Yahoo services, and others via the numerous adapters that are available for [the PHPLeague's OAuth2 client package](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client).

IMHO, OAuth2's monumentally confusing structure, ambiguity, and complexity creates excessive overhead and many opportunities for error, and it's all ultimately secured by a username and password, all of which undermines the security of the whole exercise. What doesn't help is that there is no standardisation, and the procedures you must follow to obtain tokens can be completely different across providers (hence the need for different adapters), and is subject to frequent change, making it hard to document. However, since Google imposes it on everyone, you have no choice but to go along with it.